# Does erasing cookies/history cause Google Analytics to see you as a "new visitor" even if you've visited before?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

If someone uses incognito mode and visits my site 10 times, will it show up as 10 new visitors or 1 new visitor and 9 return visitors?

Thanks

Comment: The headline and the question are actually asking slightly different things. I tried to cover both in my answer but you might try and make the question a bit clearer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For asynchronous analytics you would get 10 visitors- sessions are maintained clientside, so deleting the cookie deletes session info. That is, assuming you mean someone who leaves and enters the incognito mode between visits. Else it works just like a "normal" browser session and works as you have described.

For Universal Analytics it's less clear - [Google says that UA supports cookieless tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2838718?hl=en&topic=2790009). Of course it's technically still tracking if they reset sessions, but the linked page seems to imply that indeed they can properly track users (including sessions) even without cookies. Quite possibly Google is talking about server-side implementations with the measurement protocol where the CMS generates a user id and passes it to the pageview calls (which then is used to maintain sessions on the Google server).